# MDX - Média Mensal aberta por Data

Tags: pentaho, mdx

Necessito de uma grande ajuda.

Estou trabalhando com MDX para geração de gráficos no Pentaho - CDE / CTools. E necessito realizar uma série de filtros que serão setados pelo usuário. O gráfico é uma evolução diária, e eu gostaria de adicionar uma linha de média no mesmo. Porém não está dando muito certo.

O que estou fazendo de errado? Não tenho muito conhecimento com MDX. Deveria aparecer os valores e repetir a média do mês todo, mas está repetindo os mesmos valores.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[MEDIA] AS
AVG ([MES].[MES].CurrentMember, [Measures].[QTDE])
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[QTDE], [Measures].[MEDIA]} ON COLUMNS, 
       {[DATA].[DATA].Members} ON ROWS 
from [DW20_DIA]
where Crossjoin(Crossjoin(Crossjoin({[MES].[All MESs]}, {[CAUSE].[All CAUSEs]}), {[TIPO].[All TIPOs]}), {[MODEL].[All MODELs]})
```

Com algum filtro:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[MEDIA] AS
AVG ([MES].[MES].Currentmember , [Measures].[QTDE])
SELECT NON EMPTY {[Measures].[QTDE], [Measures].[MEDIA]} ON COLUMNS, 
            NON EMPTY {[DATA].[DATA].Members} ON ROWS 
from [DW20_DIA]
where Crossjoin(Crossjoin(Crossjoin({[MES].[2016-11-01]}, {[STOP CAUSE].[All CAUSEs]}), {[TIPO].[All TIPOs]}), {[MODEL].[All MODELs]})
```

Amostra dos dados - Neste caso a média deveria ser: **7.567.743**

```
  DATA        QNTD        MEDIA         MEDIA DEVE SER
01/11/2016  7.731.442   7.731.442       7.567.743
02/11/2016  7.973.846   7.973.846       7.567.743
03/11/2016  7.430.333   7.430.333       7.567.743
04/11/2016  7.517.061   7.517.061       7.567.743
05/11/2016  6.738.677   6.738.677       7.567.743
06/11/2016  6.796.424   6.796.424       7.567.743
07/11/2016  7.631.584   7.631.584       7.567.743
08/11/2016  7.907.649   7.907.649       7.567.743
09/11/2016  8.995.933   8.995.933       7.567.743
10/11/2016  7.444.471   7.444.471       7.567.743
11/11/2016  8.039.431   8.039.431       7.567.743
12/11/2016  7.240.583   7.240.583       7.567.743
13/11/2016  6.779.103   6.779.103       7.567.743
14/11/2016  7.648.149   7.648.149       7.567.743
15/11/2016  7.641.452   7.641.452       7.567.743
```

----- Edição:

Consegui acesso aos objetos e criei uma dimensão de tempo.
Ano - Mes - Dia

Tentei esta query, mas não deu muito certo.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MEDIA] AS 
Avg( Descendants([TEMPO].[MES].CURRENTMEMBER, [TEMPO].[DATA])
, [Measures].[QTDE]
)
SELECT {[Measures].[QTDE], [Measures].[MEDIA]} ON COLUMNS,
            NON EMPTY{[TEMPO].[DATA].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [DW20_DIA]
```

Ele repete os mesmos valores para todos os dias.

Comment: Você tem uma dimensão de tempo com hierarquia (ano, mês, dia)? Ou apenas dimensões separadas de Dia, Mes e Ano como parece ser pelos "Unique Names" que estão no MDX? Normalmente você usa uma dimensão de data com hierarquia colocando o nível de dia na linha e usa a função "Descendants" para tirar a média com os membros da mesma dimensão no nível "dia"

Comment: @Pagotti, sim, são duas dimensões separadas. Construíram os objetos errado. Acabei de criar uma dimensão de tempo, vou tentar montar a query novamente. Obrigado.

Comment: @Pagotti criei uma nova dimensão... mas ainda não consegui...

Comment: `[Tempo].CurrentMember` ao invés de `[Tempo].[Mes].CurrentMember` ajuda?

Comment: @Pagotti Se eu coloco apenas `Descendants([TEMPO].CURRENTMEMBER, [TEMPO].[MES])` e no select uso `NON EMPTY{[TEMPO].[DATA].MEMBERS}` a coluna de média retorna vazia.

Comment: @Pagotti coloquei no quadro ali, como deveria aparecer... Deveria aparecer o mesmo valor pro mês todo, e alterar quando selecionado.

Comment: Talvez ele não esteja pegando todos os itens. Tente especificar para trazer todos dessa forma: `Descendants([TEMPO].CURRENTMEMBER, [TEMPO].[DATA], SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)` - Desculpe as tentativas é que não tenho um ambiente OLAP para testar.

Comment: Outra forma seria buscar os dias pelo membro pai: Descendants([TEMPO].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT, [TEMPO].[DATA]). Vou colocar essa opção como resposta, caso funcione.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56609/discussion-between-pagotti-and-fernando-a-w).

Comment: @Pagotti... Perfeito, o Parent funcionou...  Desculpe a demora, tive que sair para uma reunião, testei aqui agora e funcionou perfeitamente...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use a função `Descendants`

A função [`Descendants`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146075(v=sql.110).aspx) retorna os membros de um certo nível a partir do membro especificado. Assim, você teria como `set` de resultado para aplicar no `AVG` as datas que são filhas do mês da data corrente. Quando colocar na linha os dias, para cada linha ele vai pegar o mês daquele dia e buscar todos os dias daquele mês e tirar a média com os valores.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[MEDIA] AS 
   Avg( Descendants([TEMPO].CURRENTMEMBER.PARENT, [TEMPO].[DATA])
      , [Measures].[QTDE])
SELECT {[Measures].[QTDE], [Measures].[MEDIA]} ON COLUMNS,
       NON EMPTY{[TEMPO].[DATA].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [DW20_DIA]
```